# fixed position div, switch to relative if div on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

real new to scripting so apologies if this is basic but...

I have 2 position:fixed divs, which i want to become position:relative when a specific div is visible on screen. (ie, scroll out of screen when a div appears)

'antxt' - is the default fixed class, which i want to switch to 'andtxtscroll' when 'trig' is visible on screen. I have based this on a post found here with no luck.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('andtxt').toggleClass('andtxtscroll',

        scroll >= $('.trig').offset().top
    );
});

//trigger the scroll
$(window).scroll();//ensure if you're in current position when page is refreshed
```

see https://anthonynoyce.design/

I want the centered logo to scroll up when the next view comes into view?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('andtxt')` to `$('.andtxt')`. Class selector should be preceded by `.`

Comment: Reworked the code a bit. I have a toggle between a position: fixed div to position: absolute on a trigger point in scroll. 

This is actually switching/working but the div disappears instead of scrolling up with page as i intended??

<script>  
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.fixed').toggleClass('move',

        scroll >= $('.trig').offset().top
    );
});

//trigger the scroll
$(window).scroll();//ensure if you're in current position when page is refreshed
</script>

Example here https://anthonynoyce.design/

Comment: Making it position absolute will position it relative to closest positioned element, which in this case it is .et_pb_code_inner, as soon as position is changed to absolute your .andtxt will move to the top of this element which is already scrolled up and out of the viewport, so it is looking like disappearing

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now, thanks. So i need to think of an alternative way to achieve the same effect